# Entity Framework 5 dynamic proxy lazy loading: Does accessing null navigation property hit database everytime?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

[This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh949853.aspx) states:

> Once an entity has been loaded, any further queries for the entity will load it directly from the Object State Manager, whether you are using lazy loading or eager loading.

If I lazy load an entity using a navigation property of a proxy root entity and that navigable entity exists in the database, then all subsequent calls for that navigable entity will not result in a database hit because it has already been loaded.

Am I right in assuming that if I attempt to lazy load an entity(or collection) using navigation properties from a root entity proxy and it does *not* exist in the database -- and therefore returns null or an empty collection -- that all subsequent attempts to lazy load the same entity from the same root entity always results in a database hit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it will not. The `IsLoaded` property in `DbCollectionEntry<TEntity, TElement>` and `DbReferenceEntry<TEntity, TProperty>` is used to figure out if loading needs to happen, the actual value, whether `null` or not, is irrelevant.

Comment: Thanks! Took a look at the docs for DbReferenceEntry<TEntity, TProperty> and was hoping I could set IsLoaded false to force db hit again but doesn't look like I can.

Answer (score 0):

No, because it will already have loaded the null/empty collection value.